# Not able to link portals properly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, i build a passive mob farm. I am trying to link up the portals correctly. This is what i want as a result:

- All the portals of the passive mob farm (where the passive mobs will go in): Links to ONE portal in the nether (the kill zone)
- The kill zone (where all mobs from the passive mob farm are ported to in the nether): Links to all the passive mob farm portals in the Overworld
- The Player Portals (one in the overworld, one in the nether) - close to the passive mob farm, that link to each other to let the player be able to go travel through it. Should not interfere with the passive mob farm portals.

Coordinates:
- Kill zone portal in the nether: 35, 72, 7
- All the passive mob farm portals in the overworld: Around 262, 60, 47 (x/z +/- 20 each and y from 5 up to 62)

Those coordinates are fixed.

Now i jsut want to add the player portals but can't get it to work. I will always be ported back into the kill zone portal in the nether, when trying to port. Where do i need to put my player travel portals in order to work properly AND be as close as possible? I've tried about 5 configurations (some 40 blocks away to the right, some blocks below it, etc etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it works like this:

When entering through a portal from the overworld, the corresponding coordinates in the nether are calculated - that's x/8 and y/8 of the overworld coordinates.

then the game checks whether in a 128 block radius around these coordinates, there is a portal in the nether - if there is, it will take you to the closest.

So, if you want to portal from the overworld to a netherportal (let's call it `playerportal`) that is close to your "`kill spot`", but not quite there, build that `playerportal` (in the nether) where you want to have it, then take the coordinates, multiply them by 8, and build a portal at that spot in the overworld.

Please note, that this might initially break the mob transport - if you have multiple overworld portals to transport the mobs to the `kill spot`, and some of them link to a point in the nether that's *closer* to your `playerportal`, the mobs will go there. Make sure the Portals are spaced correctly. You might have to do some math.